# How to regenerate new pem file using old pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

> I am having my old pem file but I want to generate new pem file.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is change the key pair used to access an EC2 instance.

To generate a new private key, go to the EC2 console, select "Key Pairs" and then select "Create New Key Pair".

You can follow this Amazon EC2 Tutorial for how to use the new key pair with your instance; even though you haven't lost your key pair, the process is the same.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair